# Android audio record and processing

Tags: java, android, audio, signal-processing

I want to program a app about audio signal processing on android. First I should record the sound using the mobile app. Then I want to get the raw data (an arraylist I　think) and do FFT on it. With the data in frequency domain, I want to do some processing, mainly a noise reduction method called 'spectural subtraction', then do IFFT. Finally write the data to a .wav file. I'm new to Android and don't know which API suits my desire and where I can find FFT code. So I'm asking for help and thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

AudioRecord class is a good place to start: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html

Comment: Thanks! And the tricky thing is that I've seen that to record audio to process it it's better to use AudioRecord, because I can get the raw audio from there. But then I can't write the data to a file in a playable format. I'm also wondering how to manage the FFT(IFFT) things. Thanks!

Comment: If my answer helped you please mark it as accepted. If you have additional questions please start another thread for it. Thanks.